# golang/wasm error (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: import object field 'gojs' is not an Object)

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

Ive been using Golang and WASM to make a basic app (a basic game, but its not really that important to this question as you will soon find out) and learn about the technologies, so I set up a project and it was working fine... until it just kind of stopped working right? I'm not quite sure what I did but the code stopped executing with no errors other than
`"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: import object field 'gojs' is not an Object".` 
From this I know that it has to do with `fetch()` and I have confirmed this by commenting out different parts of my code until I narrowed it down to this line:

```
//errors here
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("main.wasm"), go.importObject).then((result) => {
    //not here (obviously not running though)
    go.run(result.instance);
});
```

this also isn't my original app, as I created a new one and (this time made sure to) copy and paste every line of code directly from this article: https://golangbot.com/webassembly-using-go/ so that I would know for sure that its not a problem with my code. (as I wouldn't have written it)

Everything I tried to do to fix this (in order):

- comment out code I wrote recently (websocket stuff)
- comment out all my go code
- comment out run
- reinstall golang and get a new wasm_exec
- comment out WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming (error stoped showing here)
- created a new project and made sure to only copy and paste from this tutorial: https://golangbot.com/webassembly-using-go/
- reinstall golang and get a new wasm_exec (again)

here's my code:

assets/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go Web Assembly")
}
```

server/server.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to start server", err)
        return
    }
}
```

static/index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="wasm_exec.js"></script>
    <script>
        const go = new Go();
        WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("main.wasm"), go.importObject).then((result) => {
        go.run(result.instance);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

static/wasm_exec.js

```
I'm not putting this here unless I need to...
```

the commands I used (from project root):
`go run server/server.go` (to run the server)
`GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go assets/build main.go` (to build the wasm file, I know I don't have to drag and drop the files into the static folder this is just temp)

This is my first question on StackOverflow so if you need anything I didn't post here just let me know.
Ive already tried my best to find something on the internet but I couldn't find anything on this error please help.

Comment: Don't know what I did but its working now. If you have this problem I would just uninstall and reinstall golang (remembering to close and reopen you cmd after each attempt) until it works. It probably something to do with packages or some weird thing that golang itself does.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I realized that this problem does not exist in Firefox. I set some flag values for "Experimental WebAssembly" in chrome for solution
see: chrome://flags

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).